# How to replace siding around deck

Tags: deck, siding, vinyl-siding

The previous owners of my house installed a small deck off the back of the house. The deck was built flush against the siding.

I am going to replace the siding on the house, so I’m wondering what to do around the deck.

Do I remove the deck so that I can remove the siding between it and the sheathing?

**Or**

Do I cut the siding around the deck to remove it, then put the new siding around the deck (*instead of behind it*)?

The new siding will be vinyl.

[image: deck image 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of siding shown in your picture is most often used to serve as both the siding and sheathing all in one. A common term for this plywood material is T-111 plywood.

You would do well to check your house construction to see if there really is a second sheathing layer. If you find that the T-111 is nailed directly to the outside of the studs you may want to reconsider removing it. Because if you do you would have to come back at more expense to install sheathing as vinyl siding cannot be mounted directly to studs. The better strategy is to just install the new siding right over the T-111.  If you do that you can then just use the pocket trim at the vinyl ends just butted up to the deck and caulked at the join.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will take a look and see if there is additional sheathing or not. The main reason for removing the existing siding first is due to rot that’s causing bulging in many spots. So even if there isn’t additional sheathing the siding may have to come off anyway.

Comment: There is sheathing under the T-111, but I’m going to install the vinyl over the existing siding anyway. I’ll use J channel around the deck per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @ARich note that it's going to be important to _replace_ the water damaged, rotting existing T1-11 siding _before_ you install your new vinyl over the top of it. The good news is that you can just use plywood/OSB of the same thickness (3/4", I believe) replacing only the bad spots and it doesn't have to be pretty!

Comment: @FreeMan Yep, that was the plan. All rotten material was replaced with OSB where necessary. Thanks!